# How to resolve property of undefined in Angular and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm learning how to work with Angular and API using mlab (MongoDB) as my database. When i try to seed, I get error

> Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined at MongoClient.connect

I have added my database credentials in my .env file and have the following code inside my seed.js file

```
require('dotenv').config();

const users = require('./users');
const contacts = require('./contacts');

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

function seedCollection(collectionName, initialRecords) {
MongoClient.connect(process.env.DB_CONN, (err, db) => {
    console.log('connected to mongodb...');

    const collection = db.collection(collectionName);

    collection.remove();

    //I have more code here
});
}

seedCollection('users', users);
seedCollection('contacts', contacts);
```

The error seems to be coming from this line `const collection = db.collection(collectionName);`

What am I doing wrong and what is the right way to defining a const?

Comment: You're ignoring the `err` argument. Check it first to see if there's an error (if there is one, it will likely be informative) before proceeding to evaluate the `db`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance that helped. Found the error and fixed it now. Issue was with an unescaped @ sign in the credentials